# using iron-session with NextJS and the new app router

Tags: authentication, next.js

Pardon my ignorance...I don't have a 100% grasp of session cookies, and authentication, which is why I am building something...to understand, then to do better...

Anyway, I am trying to get session cookies going on my nextJS app, and I am porting in the sample code from iron session...however, the examples of iron session use the pages router, which I am not using in my application.

For example, here's the login route from iron sessions examples:

```
import { Octokit } from "octokit";
import { withIronSessionApiRoute } from "iron-session/next";
import { sessionOptions } from "lib/session";
const octokit = new Octokit();

export default withIronSessionApiRoute(async (req, res) => {
  const { username } = await req.body;

  try {
    const {
      data: { login, avatar_url },
    } = await octokit.rest.users.getByUsername({ username });

    const user = { isLoggedIn: true, login, avatarUrl: avatar_url };
    req.session.user = user;
    await req.session.save();
    res.json(user);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
}, sessionOptions);
```

You can see the full code I'm referencing at: https://github.com/vvo/iron-session
follow /examples/next.js/

Right now, the problem I'm facing is that the app router in nextJS wants a POST() or GET() function for it to work properly, and I dont' have a complete grasp of how withIronSessionApiRoute() is wrapping itself around the routing.

I've looked extensively at the nextJS documentation around this, but haven't found much in migrating pages router to app router.  Any suggestions or thoughts?

I hope this question comes across cleary, if not, feel free to ask clarifying questions.

As always, thanks!
Chris Roode

Comment: Hey there, have you managed to solve it? I'm currently experiencing the same problem.

Comment: No, not currently.  Here is a link to the issue via github: https://github.com/vvo/iron-session/issues/594

This is not a feature yet.  I am using the pages router for authenticated requests, app router for everything else, and designing with a mindset of migrating once the feature is released.

Answer (score 1):

I recently migrated an application to the app router, the withIronSessionSsr method is just a wrapper for easier use, to achieve the same functionality you can just leverage the low level seal/unseal methods. Something like this (in a server component):

```
import { unsealData } from 'iron-session/edge';
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';

export default async function Page() {
  const cookieStore = cookies();

  const encryptedSession = cookieStore.get('name-of-your-cookie')?.value;

  const session = encryptedSession
    ? await unsealData(encryptedSession, {
        password: 'your-password',
      })
    : null;

  return <div>{session ? session.some_value : 'not authenticated'}</div>;
}
```

Creating the session can be tricky since you need to set the encrypted session with a cookie header either in a route handler or a middleware.

```
import { sealData } from 'iron-session/edge';

// endpoint to log in a user
export async function POST() {
  const session = JSON.stringify({
    userId: 1,
    name: 'john doe',
  });

  const encryptedSession = sealData(session, {
    password: 'your-password',
  });

  return new Response('ok', {
    status: 200,
    headers: { 'Set-Cookie': `name-of-your-cookie=${encryptedSession}` },
  });
}
```

Credits: https://github.com/vvo/iron-session/issues/594#issuecomment-1638964195

Comment: Super glad to see an answer here!  Turns out I ended up making my project split between app router and pages router for this.  It's not the prettiest, but works great since nextJS still supports the pages router.

Down the road, a refactor project will include going to all app router, and this will be helpful then!